Can’t connect PostgreSQL to my Django App in Azure VM
I am build a django app that I am deploying through a CI/CD pipeline into my Azure VM. I already created a PostgreSQL database. When I deploy my docker container in my VM and try to connect to my database I get the following error :
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at “127.0.0.1”, port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Knowing that the that I get the following when running “netstat -an | grep 5432” :
enter image description here
Can you please help me, I looked for two days in all forums for a solution for this error, but still nothing worked !
Thanks in advance.
I am expecting to be able to connect my docker container (django app) with my the VM postgresql database.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should use vm ip address instead of 127.0.0.1 for postgres address in django app.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
